# C++ Return a Variable of an object

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ currently and i have run to this problem:
Error Message: This Code should be of type bool or should be converted to bool. 
The main function must stay the same, so i was wondering, that i use the line [A] and actuall return an bool. 
The method should compare two cubics with each other, if they are the same or not the same.

Thanks in advance! :) <3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>

class cubics
{
private: 
double x,y,z;
bool var;

public: 
cubics same(cubics cube)
{ 
double difference_x = x - cube.x;
double difference_y = y - cube.y;
double difference_z = z - cube.z; 

if  ( // If the difference between two objects are 0, then both cubics are the same; epsilon is used because we calculate with double floating precision to avoid the error) 
                    (difference_x <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon( )) and 
                    (difference_y <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon( )) and 
                    (difference_z <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon( ))
                    )
                {
                    return (cube.var= true);                          // [A] I'm actually returning bool. But does the compiler want me to return the whole object!?
                }
                else
                {
                    return (cube.var=false);                          // [A]
                }
}

int main(){
cubics q2,q3;
cout << "The Cubics q2 and q3 are ";
if (q2.same(q3))                                      // <-- This line confuses me, however it must stay formally for my computerproject the same :) I understand that  it means q2.same(q3) == true, but i don't know how i can return a boolean. I tryed [A]
cout << "same." << endl;
else
cout << "not same." << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: What is going on here? `cubics cubics same(cubics cube)`

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If this function is supposed to return `bool` the signature should be `bool same(const cubics& cube) const` to adhere to C++ conventions. It's also far from clear what the mysteriously named `var` property actually does.

Comment: Tip: Instead of inventing your own `same()` function it's better to implement [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) which will mean you can do `if (q2 == q3)` without any fuss.

Comment: It's also worth noting this code is incomplete and can't be compiled since `q2` and `q3` are never defined here.

Comment: Oh. You are totally right. 

My first task was the q2.same(q3)- element structure.
My second task was operator overloading. :)
Correction:
public:
_italic_  cubics same(cubics cube) 

with the var, i wanted to have an extra boolean to return a boolean. That was my try.
I guess for you pro's it is memory leakage. 

Right:
int main(){
cubics q2, q3;
}
Thank you so much for your contribution!^^ @tadman 
Would you recommand from the i. style the Stroustroups? I guess the if statement was formally eye bleeding for you..

I am aware of:
-content check, formally check, syntax check

Comment: You don't need a var to return a value. That just clutters up your structure for no reason. Just return whatever you need to return. It's not a "memory leak", it's just a memory waste.

Comment: True. I have changed it and implemented the overloading.

Comment: The accepted way to indicate that an answer has been answered is to accept the answer, not to edit the answer into your question. (Admittedly, this is more challenging when people answer in the comments when they should answer in the answers.) The question should remain in its question form so that the next person with the same question can recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a boolean, you make the function… return a boolean.

Right now, it is trying to return an object of type `cubics`:

```
cubics same(cubics cube)
^^^^^^
```

Instead:

```
bool same(cubics cube)
^^^^
```

And `return true`, or `return false`, as appropriate.

That's it!

Your `bool var` doesn't need to exist at all.

I'd also recommend you take `cube` by reference; there's no need to take it by value, which makes a copy. So:

```
bool same(const cubics& cube)
```

Comment: Oh yeah. tadman reminded also to that! :)
Thank you!
Formatted it